# go:embed fs only works for the root with http server?

Tags: go

I have the following directory structure:

```
web/
  dist/
    index.html
main.go
```

the content of main.go:

```golang
package main

import (
    "embed"
    "io/fs"
    "net/http"
)

//go:embed web/dist
var webfs embed.FS

func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    sub, err := fs.Sub(webfs, "web/dist")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    mux.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.FS(sub)))

    http.ListenAndServe(":2222", mux)
}
```

When the code is run, I could get the content of index.html through http://127.0.0.1:2222. However, when I changed the line to:

```golang
mux.Handle("/admin/", http.FileServer(http.FS(sub)))
```

I get 404 when accessing http://127.0.0.1:2222/admin/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to strip the `/admin/` off the request path (otherwise the file server will be looking in `web/dist/admin`). e.g.

```golang
mux.Handle("/admin/", http.StripPrefix("/admin/", http.FileServer(http.FS(sub))))
```

See the docs for [`StripPrefix`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#StripPrefix) for more info.